# spl_autoload_register w/ multiple directories

Tags: php

When I execute the following code:

```
// autoload classes
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once("$class.php");
});
```

It works for all classes contained in the same directory as the script. However, any classes located in another directory will fail to load. The following solution works:

```
define('ABSOLUTE_PATH', "/var/www/application");

// autoload classes
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    // class directories
    $dir = array(ABSOLUTE_PATH,
                 ABSOLUTE_PATH . '/models');

    foreach($dir as $path) {
        $file = sprintf('%s/%s.php', $path, $class);
        if(is_file($file)) {
            require_once($file);
        }
    }
});
```

But this feels ugly. I've read that [you can use namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#92514) but I can't seem to get that or anything else to work. Can someone please show me a more elegant solution, if one exists, where I don't have to hard-code the directory paths?

Comment: Why not use the autoloader simply to load each individual class as it's needed, rather than a whole directory of files whether they're needed or not

Comment: @MarkBaker how do you mean?

Comment: You request a new model class, the autoloader loads every single model class file, whether you requested that or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to autoload classes, you could use the PSR-0 standard at https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

The gist for SplClassLoader is located here https://gist.github.com/221634

Answer (score 0):

Yep. You can use spl_autoload_register to autoload classes from multiple directories. That includes classes with **namespaces**. :)

6 lines of code, brackets included:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

   $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';

   if(file_exists($file)) {

      require_once $file;

   } // end if

});
```

Try it out and let me know if there's anything I can help with.

Cheers :)